# Composer Autoloading PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-0

I need help with composer autoloader. Well in my opinion I have set up everything correctly, but still I am having an error "class has been not found".

So maybe someone here will be able to help me.
Look at the screenshoots below to understand the way I structured my project and the way I autoloaded namespace for my Test class.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The question is why I am having an error, class has been not found?

Comment: did you composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Yep it did. So I guess it should works, cuz "autoload_namespaces.php" has 'controller\\' => array($baseDir . '/app')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re `autoload` array is wrong in your **composer.json** file. If your root namespace is `app` then it should look like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "app": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use your classes in the `app` namespace like this:

```
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$test = new \app\controller\Test();
```

However, I would camel-case your namespaces, as is the PSR way. So in my case, I have a directory structure like this:

- src/

  - MCB/

    - Controller/

      - PagesController.php
- vendor/

  - autoload.php

My **composer.json** file looks like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MCB": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

And I can then use my classes like this:

```
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$controller = new \MCB\Controller\PagesController();
```

Comment: Thank you mate. Working well. I will go for your structure, looks clear comparing to my one. :)